# Codecs, Premiere Pro & Quicktime: Import or Play Error

Tags: windows, video, codec, adobe-premiere

### Original Question

I've been using a FS-H200 (not the Pro variant) recorder with a JVC ProHD camera. I have been shooting with the `DTE FORMAT` to `Quicktime (.mov)`. I copied the files to an external hard drive and am now trying to edit.

The files will play back in VLC, as they would be expected to. However they will not import into Adobe Premiere CS5.5, instead giving an error:

> Unsupported format or damaged file.

Quicktime gives the following error when attempting to play the files:

> Error -2002: a bad public movie atom was found in the movie (`Filename`)

To try and fix this, I have installed the following codec packs:

- K-Lite Codec Pack 64-bit Full (version 5.9, latest)
- K-Lite Codec Pack 32-bit Full (version 8.4, latest)
- MainConcept Codec Suite (Broadcast) v5.1 for Adobe CS5
- Reinstalled Quicktime with new download from Apple

The same errors and problems still exist.

From this I can assume that there is an issue with Quicktime and that is what Premiere is using as an encoder/decoder for the codec. Is there any way to fix this?

---

From looking at the "Codec Information" from VLC:

> **Stream 0**
>
> - Type: Video
> - Codec: MPEG-1/2 (mpgv)
> - Language: English
> - Resolution: 1280 x 720
> - Frame Rate: 25
>
> **Stream 1**
>
> - Type: Audio
> - Codec: PCM S16 BE (twos)
> - Language: English
> - Channels: Stereo
> - Sample Rate: 48000 Hz
> - Bits per sample: 16

---

Other computer specs:

- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (SP1)
- Gigabyte Z68X-UD3-B3
- Intel i7-2600K
- 16GB DDR3
- 2TB WD 7200RPM SATA 6Gb/s
- LaCie d2 Quadra 2TB v3 7200RPM (External HDD)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti Golden Sample

---

### Updates

**2012-03-11 @ 2050 AEDT**

MPEG Steamclip doesn't recognise, play or convert the footage.

> File open error: unrecognised file type.
>
> *[Open Anyway]*
>
> File open error: can't find video or audio tracks.

**2012-03-24 @ 1920 AEDT**

Had to transcode the footage. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `Camatasia Studio` with a lower resolution.

You could also try [installing these codecs](http://www.freecodecs.net/fc/MpegDecoder012.zip).